# copy paste table from excel sheet lo ckeditor5 loses text formating

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

[ckeditor5] copy paste table from excel sheet lo ckeditor5 loses text formating, such as background color, font etc.

More detail can be found here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/13586